# How can I "integration test" my AngularJS $destroy event handler?

Tags: angularjs

I've written code in my controllers to clean up resources on a $destroy event.  It's straightforward to write unit tests to verify the operation of my cleanup method, but it's reasonable to wonder this: When will my app ever get a $destroy event?  What can I do as a user in my browser to make my app get a $destroy event?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

> Removes the current scope (and all of its children) from the parent
>   scope. Removal implies that calls to $digest() will no longer
>   propagate to the current scope and its children. Removal also implies
>   that the current scope is eligible for garbage collection.
>
> The $destroy() is usually used by directives such as ngRepeat for
>   managing the unrolling of the loop.
>
> Just before a scope is destroyed, a $destroy event is broadcasted on
>   this scope. Application code can register a $destroy event handler
>   that will give it a chance to perform any necessary cleanup.
>
> Note that, in AngularJS, there is also a $destroy jQuery event, which
>   can be used to clean up DOM bindings before an element is removed from
>   the DOM.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

It appears there are a couple of things related to $destroy.  My basic understanding of this is that any time a scope is no longer needed navigating away from some view and now the controller/scope used for that view is no longer needed or some DOM element is removed $destroy is called.  The places I've seen this actually in use are for cleaning up timers or listeners so that the memory can be garbage collected.